# listview items centered but left aligned when selected

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I have a listview with a single column with values centered down every row.  I'm just trying to find out what's causing the entries to get pushed to the left of the column everytime one of the entries is selected with a mouse or keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: The ListView has quite a few different modes. What settings are you using to get the items to center to begin with?

Comment: I am only using the column.add parameters to center everything.  listview1.Columns.Add("", 100,HorizontalAlignment.Center)

Comment: The first column in a ListView cannot be centered. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155921/text-align-column-in-listview-first-column-cannot-be-centered) for a workaround