# How to align the first column of listView to the right?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I can align the text of every column to the right besides the first one. It simply doesn't let me change the TextAlign property of the first column.

I've tried this, but it didn't work:
`listView1.Columns[0].TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;`

Image of where issue is located:

[image]

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can u provide a sample screen shot.

Comment: @user3501749 https://imgur.com/a/3pQKW

Comment: What happens if you put non-Hebrew characters? Will it allow you to select Right?

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker no, it still doesn't allow me to select anything but Left.

Comment: Okay, this post seems to be the issue, and should get you in the right direction. It's for VB.net but it's the same concept and controls: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155921/text-align-column-in-listview-first-column-cannot-be-centered

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker Yeah the solution given there works. Thank you!

Comment: @svantov You are very welcome :)